# Accessing the calling Service from ServiceRunner?

Tags: servicestack

I want to access the calling `Service` from inside the `ServiceRunner` `OnBeforeRequest()`method in order to get to an object in the calling service class. In MVC, I can create a class `BaseController` that overrides `OnActionExecuting()` and I can get to `Data` easily. However, using `ServiceRunner`, since it's not derived from Service, I don't see a way to get to the `Service` object.

Sample service:

```cs
public class ProductsService : Service
{
    private MyData _data = new MyData();

    public MyData Data
    {
         get { return _data; }
    }

    public object Get(GetProduct request)
    {
         // ...
         return product;
    }
}
```

In my custom `ServiceRunner`, how do I retrieve the `ProductsService` object from `OnBeforeRequest()` so I can get to `Data`?

```cs
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
{
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, T request)
    {
        // var productService = ?

        base.OnBeforeExecute(requestContext, request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging, it looks like this cannot be done. The Service action is available in the `ServiceRunner` as an unnamed lamdba delegate. There is no reference to the Service.

I have instead found a workaround. I first registered MyData in `AppHost.Configure()` using

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<MyData>();
```

I moved the MyData declaration to a filter attribute like this:

```
public class UseMyDataAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public MyData Data { get; set; } // injected by Funq IoC. 

    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object responseDto)
    {
        Data.SessionID = req.GetSessionId();
    }
}
```

This way I can apply `[UseMyData]` to the `ProductsService` class and be able to set the Session ID to `Data`.